# Spring Boot ERP system best delete operation strategy

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-data-jpa

i am developing one ERP system for small and medium sized organization, i stuck when comes to delete operation for entities.
  Right now i have one Project entity and Task entity, i.e. one project has many Tasks
now i have three options while delete operation is performed.

1> either delete data permanently from database, with child data
i.e. if project is deleted then also delete it's associated tasks

here problem is : we won't be able to get back, once it is deleted.

2> either only set isDeleted to true.

here problem is : if any entity has isDeleted to true, then it's associated entity can fetch it through Getter method (so it is not a good idea)
 if Project P1 has three tasks T1, T2, T3, with Fetch Type EAGER.
e.g. if i set Task T1 as isDeleted to true then, if i get project P1 it will also get three tasks along with T1, because still there is a relationship between them, T1 is only updated to isDeleted to true.

3> or store all events(CRUD) of an entity in separate history tables

here problem is : database size will be in multiple times then regular database.

Comment: As you don't really want to actually delete the data, then why not, maintain a separate table and moved those deleted data into that table. Whenever you need to restore just swap it back to main table.

Comment: so, you mean i will have one separate replica of actual database structure, where i will have only deleted data ?

Comment: Yes! also isDeleted flag will not be necessary anymore. And it will not be problematic for other related datas also.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, i appreciate and follow this one

Comment: Welcome! Happy to help. I've also added those as answer. If it really solve your problem you can upvote and accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Actually deleting the data, and better than isDeleted, try deletedDate. If deleted_date is null, product is active. If not, The date on which it is deleted will be set.

Now on the entity, just write

```
@DynamicInsert
@SQLDelete(sql =
        "UPDATE post SET deleted_date=now() " +
                "WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "deleted_date IS NULL ")
class User{
}
```

here, `@SQLDelete` will make sure when you call the delete method, It doesn't actually delete the entity, but sets its deleted date to when it was deleted.

`@Where` cause will make sure whenever any entity is called, it adds the code `AND deleted_date IS NULL` to its corresponding hibernate query fired, so only the non deleted ones will be fetched.

Comment: Thanks ROHON for this very nice solution, sure i'm interested to use this one

Comment: can you help me for this one ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000694/spring-boot-create-generic-crud-service-with-dto-pattern

Comment: Also, ROHAN suppose, after 6 months if i want to remove old(deleted) data(deleted_date IS NOT NULL) permanently, how can i do that ?

Comment: You could simply write a native query to delete the data in any of your Repository methods.

Answer (score 0):

Summary from the comment:

> 1> either delete data permanently from database, with child data
>   i.e. if project is deleted then also delete it's associated tasks
>
> here problem is : we won't be able to get back, once it is deleted.

You actually don't want to delete those data. You just want sudo delete those datas and also want to have the ability to restore deleted data. 
**Solution**: You can either mark this data deleted (could be problematic) or maintain separate table/schema where you'll only store the deleted datas. 
By moving this to separate table you don't need to worry about deleted flags and other complex parent child relations.

> 2> either only set isDeleted to true.
>
> 3> or store all events(CRUD) of an entity in separate history tables

Also this two problem will be solved automatically if you follow that(separated deleted data) approach.